# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Paypal library

Tags: android, paypal

I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` after checking out and resulting into a cancelled transaction. I am using SANDBOX test account.

I am providing the chunks from stack trace here:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-481
E/AndroidRuntime(15495): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=6
at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.getPayType(Unknown Source)
at com.paypal.android.a.m.f(Unknown Source)
at com.paypal.android.a.b.y(Unknown Source)
at com.paypal.android.a.b.f(Unknown Source)
at com.paypal.android.a.k.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Payment Task class is -

```
public class PaymentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

private Handler mHandler;
private Activity mActivity;

// The PayPal server to be used - can also be ENV_NONE and ENV_LIVE
private static final int server = PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX;

// The ID of your application that you received from PayPal
private static final String appID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";

public PaymentTask(Activity mActivity, Handler mHandler){
    super();
    this.mHandler = mHandler;
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
    // If the library is already initialized, then we don't need to initialize it again.
    if(pp == null) {
        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(mActivity, appID, server);

        pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.

        pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER); 
        // Set to true if the transaction will require shipping.
        pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
        pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

Code being executed on click of Check-out button -

```
            PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
            newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt("10"));
            newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
            newPayment.setRecipient("my.mail@gmail.com");
            newPayment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS);
            newPayment.setMerchantName("Support the initiative");
            // Sets the memo. This memo will be part of the notification sent by PayPal to the necessary parties.
            newPayment.setMemo("Thanks for contributing generously!");
            Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, getSherlockActivity());
            startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, request);
        }

        mCheckoutButton.updateButton();
```

Comment: You'll need to provide something more than that for us too root out your problem, because what this says is that your trying to access something at position 6 when your array has 4 items[0-3]

Comment: Hi @DanielFigueroa, I have edited my question just in case if it can be of any help

Comment: Which version of `PayPal MPL` are you using? Can you test your code with `version 1.5.5.44` and update your trace if this issue still occurs?

Comment: Hi @Akdeniz, I am using 1.5.5.44 version of PayPal_MPL. Please let me know if I still have to update the stack trace. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `PayPal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS`, which is payment sub type,  as payment type. You should use one of these to define type of payment: `PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS`, `PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE`, `PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_PERSONAL` or `PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_NONE`.

And if you want to set subtype, set it like this:

```
newPayment.setPaymentSubtype(PayPal.PAYMENT_SUBTYPE_DONATIONS);
```